# Blender keymap from Mac to Windows

Tags: interface, export, customization, shortcut

Lately I plan to migrate from Mac to Windows because Mac's lacking support to Nvidia GPU. But I have lots of customized keymap on my Mac's Blender. I know I can export/import keymap, but I'm not sure if it works across platforms. Especially I have a lot of shortcuts do different things when pressing `Cmd` and `Ctrl`, while Windows doesn't have `Cmd` key. I'd need to think twice if I cannot use my keymap.

Comment: so what does it give if you import your shortcuts? (make sure to save your current shortcuts before importing)

Comment: @moonboots I haven't ordered my windows PC yet so I can't test, that's why I'm asking here. If I need to change lots of shortcut manually I'd probably not bother.

Comment: Exported .py file can be open in text edit and find/replace cmd to ctrl or something that is not used ofter in shortcuts ... but yes it will be very conflicting transfer :) Also there are other shortcuts on PC not accesible on Mac ... so probably better to start from scratch to avoid messy behaviour.

Comment: I'm not a Mac user, but the easiest (but not so fast) way is to write them down, and customize them in the preferences, since both OS are very different. U can customize just the most important ones tho